# Writing snippet for require in vim for nodejs?

Tags: node.js, vim, snipmate

This is the current snippet that i am using

```
snippet req
  const ${1:} = require('$1');
```

As you might have guessed it works well with packages that i installed from `npm` but not so well for local file. Suppose i have a file at `../user.js` that i want to include in my nodejs project rather than showing up as

```
const ../user.js = require('../user.js');
```

I would like it to be as

```
const user = require('../user.js');
```

from what i assume i would somehow have to split the file path using `/` get last element and again get first element after exploding with `.` which would work well with both global install and local file inclusion. Problem is that i am new to `snipmate` and have not figured out how can this be achieved. Any nudge in right direction is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance for helping me out.

#### Update

Refering to snipmate documentation [here](https://github.com/msanders/snipmate.vim/blob/master/doc/snipMate.txt#L123), i found that i can use `system` to utilize standard unix commands to perform operation on string. Now i am still stuck up on how to exactly pass `$1` inside the system. Here is the updated code that i have

```
snippet req
  const `system('echo $1')` = require('${1:}');
```

Comment: How well would https://github.com/honza/vim-snippets/blob/master/snippets/javascript/javascript.node.snippets#L7 work?

Comment: @JeremyPridemore let me try that and get back to you :)

Comment: @JeremyPridemore nope thats just more typing for me... I could achieve the same using `const ${1} = require('${2}');` exploding the string might make my requrie process faster... Plus some nice learning experience on how to process variables in snipmate :)

Comment: Ah, ok. I use vim and node, but had never heard of vim-snippet before. If that doesn't do it, I'm not entirely sure. Good luck!

Comment: @JeremyPridemore have a look now if you can help somehow :)

Answer (score 3):

The original snipMate cannot manipulate mirrored tabstops; I think [UltiSnips](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2715) allows this, though. (The `` `...` `` interpolation is only executed only during snippet expansion; you cannot pass `$1` into it.)

If you don't want to switch, you can split the definition of the included file into a path and module name, and only mirror the latter into the variable name:

```
snippet req
    const $2 = require('${1:path/}${2:module}');
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have your snippet setup, but now that you can send it to bash, I'd assume that you can pipe it through `grep` to pull out the part of the value that you want. If you put in something like `../models/user.js` it should just pull the `user.js` out.

```
snippet req
  const `system('echo $1 | grep -Po "(?<=/)[^/]*$"')` = require('${1:}');
```

Comment: Still stuck on sending to `system` the docs are not that clear on snipmate :( still figuring out how to set variable and pass to system.